# Ubuntu 13.10 won't allow me to change file permissions. Fresh install

Tags: 13.10, permissions, system

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 13.10 and made myself an admin account. I had a problem with closing my laptop and the system suspending so I went into change the /etc/systemd/logind.conf to change the line to ignore it but when I tried the file was "read-only," the file would not allow me to mess with it. I immediately went into properties to change permissions and it said "You are not the owner. So you cannot change these permissions."

It says this for system files and folders not just this one specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As a normal user, you are not allowed to edit system files. However, in addition to being a normal user, you are also a member of the `sudo` group, meaning that you have the right to *elevate* your privileges.

If you're in a terminal, then you can do `sudo nano filename` in order to edit it, or if you prefer using GUI applications, then you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksu gedit`, which will run the text editor as the system administrator, which does have the right to edit any file. The same is true for the file browser, Nautilus. If you want to run it as super-user, run `gksu nautilus` instead.